# HTML post Perl script to text file

Tags: html, perl, unix

I have a Perl script (I didn't write it) that takes a POST from an html page and it displays a certain section of a txt file to a webpage.  The problem is, now I need it to also make a text file of that section to a text file on our Unix server.  Any help?  Code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print '<pre>';
read(STDIN, $buf, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
#print "$buf\n";
#print "$REMOTE_USER = $REMOTE_USER\n";
@pairs = split(/&/, $buf);
#print "$pairs\n";
($txt_HRcode, $lc_HRcode) = split(/=/,$pairs[0]);
#print "$txt_HRcode\n";

#$HRcode = " HRcode:  E2PSYAA0";
$HRcode = " HRcode:  F8".uc($lc_HRcode)."0";
#print "$HRcode\n"; 

open(LINEFIND, "grep -n \"$HRcode\" /release/ucpmr/ucpmr.txt |") or die print "Can't Open File" ;
$line_num = <LINEFIND>;
#print "$line_num\n";
#if($line_num !~ m/$HRcode/) {print "SEQUENCE CODE NOT FOUND"; die()};
($sline, $hrd, $lin_text) = split(/:/, $line_num);
$beg_line = ($sline - 2);
$end_line = ($beg_line + 10000);
#print "$beg_line\n";
#print "$end_line\n";
close(LINEFIND);

open(DISP, "/release/ucpmr/ucpmr.txt") or die print "File is no longer in History. Press Back to Return";
for($incr=1; $incr <= $end_line; $incr +=1)
{$line = <DISP>;
    if($incr > $beg_line) {
    if($incr >$sline){ 
        if($line =~ m/HRcode:  F8/){
        if($line !~ m/$HRcode/) {$quit_line =  $incr-3 ; last;

close(DISP);}}}}}

open(PRINTFIND, "/release/ucpmr/ucpmr.txt") or die print "File is no longer in History. Press Back to Return";
for($incr=1; $incr <= $quit_line; $incr +=1)
{$line = <PRINTFIND>;
#$line =~ s/\d\d\d-\d\d-/XXX-XX-/;
    if($incr > $beg_line) {print"$line";}}
#print "quit line is : $quit_line\n";

print "</pre>";
```

Comment: Not very clear what you want to do. You want to save something to a text file? On the same server where this runs? In any case, this is an awful script. You're better off rewriting it nicely in your favorite language.

Comment: Yeah, this is part of a "Other Duties as Assigned".  And the programmer that wrote this is long gone.  But basically, this displays a certain part of a txt file to a web page.  I also need it to put it in a text file in this directory /release/ucpmr/.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the end part, starting from `open(PRINTFIND, ...` like this:

```
open(PRINTFIND, "/release/ucpmr/ucpmr.txt") or die print "File is no longer in History. Press Back to Return";
open(my $fh, '>/release/ucpmr/TEXT_FILE_NAME.txt');
for($incr=1; $incr <= $quit_line; $incr +=1)
{$line = <PRINTFIND>;
#$line =~ s/\d\d\d-\d\d-/XXX-XX-/;
    if($incr > $beg_line) {print"$line"; print $fh $line; }}
#print "quit line is : $quit_line\n";

print "</pre>";
```

... but dude, if you're a .NET guy, do yourself a favor and rewrite this mess in .NET, seriously...

Comment: I am getting GLOB(0x4002662c) errors and nothing getting written to file?  Not sure what is going on.

Comment: @user3092474 ah I made a mistake. There should be no comma in `print $fh $line;` there.

Answer (score 0):

```
open(my $fh, '>', '/release/ucpmr/TEXT_FILE_NAME.txt');
print $fh FILE_CONTENT;
close $fh;
```

like this?

Comment: I'm a .NET guy so please bare with me, do I put this at the end of the script?

Comment: yes put it at the end of the script. replace TEXT_FILE_NAME with the name of the text file you wish to output, and replace FILE_CONTENT with whatever variable or content you wish to print to the file. 3rd line closes the file.